# Entire Window click not working C#

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

I had created a simple C# program with Mainform.cs, Mainform.Designer.cs and Program.cs files with SharpDevelop.

In that, i added a label at Point(10,10) in the form like this:

```
l.Text="Welcome";
l.Location=new System.Drawing.Point(10,10);
l.Size=new System.Drawing.Size(100,100);
mainForm.Controls.Add(l);
```

And then added an event handler for identifying mouse clicking on the form. When clicking a label to change its text.

```
l.Text="Clicked";
```

But it only changes text when clicking point less than (10,10). How to make it to change text when clicking anywhere on the window?

Thanks!

Comment: Attach the same event handler also to label's `Clicked` event, not only the form's event.

Comment: *And then added an event handler for identifying mouse clicking on the form.  * Please post it!

Comment: I believe the above test will work for any click falling outside the label bounds, not just below the (10,10) point.

Comment: @MarioVernari yes you are right...Clicking on label doesnot work...

Comment: @BartoszKP worked...But clicking on label doesnot work

Comment: I'm confused, so did it work or not? If not, then perhaps update the question. Providing the relevant code would also be helpful.

Comment: @BartoszKP add as an answer i will accept

Comment: The Click event is raised on the Label control when you click on the label instead of the rest of the window.

Not really sure if this is worth fixing, but an obvious approach would be to display the location in a StatusStrip instead.  Or to not use a Label control, they are very wasteful anyway, and simply draw the position with the form's Paint event.  Call this.Invalidate() to ask for a repaint.

Answer (score 2):

Attach the same event handler also to label's Clicked event, not only the form's event. In the version you've described the click events are being consumed by the `Label` control, and not being passed to the form.

Answer (score 2):

Of course attaching the same `handler` for both the `Click` event of your `Form` and your `Label` is OK, however what if you add more containers with nested relationship? I would go for a `global Click event` solution by using an `IMessageFilter`, something like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form, IMessageFilter {
   public Form1(){
     InitializeComponent();
     Application.AddMessageFilter(this);
     //Try this to see it in action
     GlobalClick += (s,e) => {
        l.Text = "Clicked";
     };
   }
   public event EventHandler GlobalClick;
   public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m){
     if(m.Msg == 0x202){//WM_LBUTTONUP
        EventHandler handler = GlobalClick;
        if(handler != null) handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
     }
     return false;
   }
}
```